# Anyone want to write a blog post about Salvation?

Tags: discussion, blog

One of our regular contributors isn't going to be able to write a July post on Salvation as it concerns [Faith and Works](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/947/4).  Sooooooo..... If anyone wants to take a shot at it, please respond and get your chance of a lifetime, you may like it so much that you want to be a regular contributor!

Evangelicals, Catholics and Methodists (even Calvinists) are covered, but there's room for duplication in this fairly broad topic so don't be shy!

Comment: should note I'm covering the Calvinist position as well...

Comment: What's the difference between Calvinist and Methodist anyway?

Comment: Ahh, [enlightenment](http://reapthevision.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/calvinism-vs-methodism/)

Comment: @PeterTurner What do you have against Evangelicals? :-|

Comment: @MonikaMichael: We have three (four?) blog authors for July that hold those respective doctrinal views, so we don't need a repeat view.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Ohk.. If you need a clueless knucklehead without any doctrinal views, you let me know.

Comment: @PeterTurner: That article is pretty good at explaining the difference; however, it was Jacobus Arminius rather than John Wesley who formulated the alternative to Calvinism. Most Methodists are Arminian, but there have always been a few Calvinists in the Methdist movement--including George Whitefield, one of the founders of the movement. Wesley and Whitefield agreed to disagree about this point and focus on evangelism in the American colonies.

Comment: @MonikaMichael: If you have a view on the role of faith and/or works in salvation, you're welcome to share it!

Comment: @MonikaMichael outside of the things I would gladly spend hours arguing with Evangelicals about, I haven't got anything against them.  However, I edited the post on account of how bad that form of humor works across the world. If you want to write for us please, please, please do! you'd be the fulfillment of [two blog posts](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/955/wanted-female-contributors-for-eschewmenical)

Comment: @PeterTurner I would looove to write for the blog. (Although I don’t know how a woman’s opinion would help in creating a different perspective, Salvation sounds like a pretty neutral topic). Anyway I'll give it a shot over the weekend and let you know.

Comment: @PeterTurner PS: Please remove that Cute Baby from your profile pic. It’s driving me crazy having to think about how he looks from the front.

Comment: @monika that's a good idea. He's over a year old now!

Comment: @MonikaMichael if you're interested in the 5th author for this month (no commitment beyond this post required). Please drop me a line in the blog chatroom: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2567/eschewmenical-blog-room

Comment: There may have originally been very good reasons for posting a request for author in the discuss-CSE forum, but now that the original article is done, leaving it out here can generate confusion years later.

Comment: @pterandon So add an answer to this post that says what the final outcome was (and links to it if such a post was written). That's the best way to tie off a question you think is a loose end.